# Why won't the iterations in my monte-carlo simulation total?

Tags: python, finance, montecarlo

Im attempting to perform a monte-carlo simualtion on a set of loans with different values and different probability of default. The idea is that a loan defualts if the random number generator produces a number that is less than the probability of default of that loan. When this occurs the total value of that loan is the beginning of the total loss of that iteration. The loop continues across the set of loans and should continue to total the loans which have had PDs more than the what the random number produces. A final total is output and needs to be stored. This process continues across the whole MC simualtion where each total loss gets stored.

Now, there seems to be three main issues when ive attempted to perform this in python:

1. The random number in the if statement isn't correctly pairing the ith random number with the ith probability of default
2. The loop is collecting the loss across that one iteration/set of loans
3. The monte-carlo simulation isn't collecting all the total losses across all the 10000 iterations

What is missing from my code that fixes these issues?

```
import random 
pd_vector=df.loc[:,"pd"] #vector of all probability of defaults
value_vector=df.loc[:,"Value"] #vector of all value of loans
N = len(df)#sets size of portfoliio
M = 10000 #number of terations to be performed
for i in range(N):
    randn =(random.random())

for i in range (0,M): #monte-carlo simulation
    loss = 0 #initailisng the total loss

    for i in range (0,N): #loop for the portfolio of loans 
        if randn[i] < pd_vector[i]: #when the ith random number if less than the ith probability of default, the ith loan defaults 
                loss[i] = loss + value_vector[i] #obtaining a running total of losses across the portfolio
        x = loss #retreiving the total loss for that one iteration

    TotalLoss = sum(x) #summation of the loss for each iteration
    ExpectedLoss = TotalLoss/M #getting a mean total loss
```

Comment: The `for i in range(N)` loop does nothing useful, check the indentation.

Comment: Assigning to a variable inside a loop doesn't magically cause the variable to turn into a list, it just overwrites the previous value.  You do this with both `randn` and `x`.  To keep all values, you have to explicitly initialize the variable as a list, and then append to it.

Comment: @jasonharper how would I change the variable into a list. Is that for both the 'pd_vector' and 'value_vector'?. Or is that only needed for 'randn' and 'x'?